# NullPointer while using Cursor

Tags: android, cursor, nullpointerexception

I couldn't find a suitable title for my question. Here is the problem... After `syso`'ing the statement in `getData()`, it should print the values in the cursor, `cMainTable`, using the statement in `displayDataForMainTable()`. But, it doesn't. There are no exceptions, and errors. I have also kept the output that i get in the LogCat. Can someone help me with, why there is no output after the first print.

```
try {
    pm = new PortfolioManager(this);
    cMainTable = pm.getData("mainTable");
    if (cMainTable.equals(null)) {
        System.out.println("Null is returned");
    }
    displayDataForMainTable(cMainTable);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("problem at Oncreate Method");
}
```

`getData()` method:

```
public Cursor getData(String string) {
    System.out.println("Getting Data for Table " + string);
    c = sqlDB.rawQuery("select * from " + string, null);      
    return c;
}
```

`displayDataForMainTable()` method:

```
private void displayDataForMainTable(Cursor c2) {
    try {
        if (c2 != null) {
            if (c2.getCount() > 0) {
                c2.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String SNo = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("scriptnumber"));
                    String SName = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("scriptname"));
                    int quant = Integer.parseInt(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("totalquantity")));
                    double avg = Double.parseDouble(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("averageprice")));
                    double cur = Double.parseDouble(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("currentprice")));
                    double log = Double.parseDouble(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("lossorgain")));
                    System.out.println("Inserted Values are ::: " + SNo
                            + " " + SName + " " + String.valueOf(quant)
                            + " " + String.valueOf(avg) + " "
                            + String.valueOf(cur) + " "
                            + String.valueOf(log));
                } while (c2.moveToNext());
            }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Cursor c2 is Empty");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in displayDataForMainTable");
    }
}
```

output

```
01-18 11:02:27.523: D/dalvikvm(468): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 53% free 2567K/5379K, external 2090K/2137K, paused 45ms
01-18 11:02:33.983: I/System.out(468): Getting Data for Table mainTable
01-18 11:02:36.584: W/KeyCharacterMap(468): No keyboard for id 0
01-18 11:02:36.584: W/KeyCharacterMap(468): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Edit 1 ::: 
I have modified the `getData()` as suggested by Nasser, but the output remains the same..

```
public Cursor getData(String string) {
    System.out.println("Getting Data for Table "+string);
    String table = string;
    sqlDB = getReadableDatabase();
    c = sqlDB.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    //c = sqlDB.rawQuery("select * from "+string, null);        
    return c;
}
```

As I read, passing `null` to the columns(2nd argument) will return all the rows. If this is correct, then the result is the same.

Comment: Seems you get a `Cursor` back with no data in it. Check if there are some records in your `mainTable`.

Comment: check this answer..[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331351/cursor-is-returning-zero-when-called-from-broadcast-receiver-class/14331830#14331830]

Comment: @Henry, the problem is i don't have firefox in my system. Only IE. Is there any other way to check the values.

Comment: @Nasser How would i write the select statement using the query(). Can you provide me the syntax?

Comment: @VamsiChalla you can inspect the database with the sqlite3 tool http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html that is installed in the android emulator.

Comment: Ok, will try it out. Thanks!!! Any other solution in the mean time?

Comment: @Nasser, I have tried the solution that you have shown, but it gives the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Eclipse has shown mercy on me and is displaying the output. Fought for over 4 hours changing code, surfing, finally ended up with no changes in code.

No matter how smart you are as a coder, IDEs always make you feel a novice.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should not return cursor from db instead of that create a setterGetter class set data in its object and return array of that object..

here's my code for same.. try..

also put logs there so u'll get idea about what is going on..

```
public ArrayList<ContactSetterGetter> getAllNumbers() {
    ArrayList<ContactSetterGetter> setterList = new ArrayList<ContactSetterGetter>();
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(C_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"contact_number"},null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.getCount() != 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            ContactSetterGetter setter = new ContactSetterGetter();
            setter.setContactNumber(c.getString(0));
            setterList.add(setter);
        } while (c.moveToNext());


    }else{
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return setterList;
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return setterList;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but the rawQuery always worked fine. Why is it not working now?

Comment: if u want to use rawQuery u can use, i just wanted to tell u that u have to return ArrayList instead cursor, which gives u chance to check what is happning in db.